# Access 2016 sending an automated email at timed intervals

Tags: email, ms-access, report

It's a number of years since I have used Access and I'm creating an asset database using Access 2016 and need to send an automated email with a report that will show assets that are due to be refreshed in the next year, six months, 3 months, then 2 months then 1 month. The report does have a date field called refresh date.

I have see details on how to send an email from access but I cannot find how to automatically run the report and for it to search by the date field?

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Please supply more details. As it stands, this question is too broad to get a proper answer on SO. You may want to break this down into several questions (for example getting the records needed based on the date and then running the report automatically). If you do, please include the code that you have and where the specific problem is.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to launch your access application from the Task Scheduler. That way you can setup in detail when to launch the application. Then within the application you can produce the report based on the current date.
You need to:
-Setup Task Scheduler to launch the application at the desired times.
-Set macro Autorun to launch a VBA script.
-The VBA script checks if the given conditions are true. If so it produces the report, exports it as a PDF file and makes the email with the file file.

Please specify your question more in case you need further help on "and for it to search by the date field?".

Answer (score 0):

You could set a timer on the form that checks if Now() = date on the form + X number of days (30, 60, 90, 180, 365) and if it hits one of them it sends the appropriate email.

If the DB is open all the time have it run once a day (timer interval of 86400000 ms).

If it is going to be open but not all the time have the interval set to a lower amount.

Comment: The risk with this solution is if the form is not opened at all. Of course it may be done on the main form that is open everytime as the frontend is lanched. But are we sure the application is going to be run at all? Only the OP knows the answer to this.